# Add keyframes animation to material-ui styled component. React

Tags: reactjs, animation, material-ui, create-react-app

I need to use key frames animation with [react material-ui(version ^5.0.0)](https://next.material-ui.com/). I'm using [styled](https://next.material-ui.com/system/styled/#main-content) components to give style to my jsx elements. Now I need to use keyframes animation with in this styled component, but its giving me error. Previously I've used keyframes with in createStyle and it worked perfectly but now under styled component its not working. Would appreciate any help.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ah, I was importing the wrong module, it needed to be imported from `import { styled } from "@mui/material/styles";`  and not `import { styled } from "@mui/styles";` . My bad. I still hope this helps somebody out there.

[image]

Comment: It certainly did, thank you Waleed!